# Google App Script File Moving files uploaded to multiple folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I'm trying upload files to multiple folders in drive with a google form. The user can select more than 1 destination (check box anser) and upload 1 to 5 files. What I have:

a response/folder with the uploaded files.

the response of the users in which folder they want to send the files (1 to 47 folders)

I will appreciate any help to resolve and learn, all the code that used I got it online.

```
    const FoldeRespnseID=''
    const MainFolder=''
    
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
      const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
      const formResponses = form.getResponses();
      const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1].getItemResponses();
      rename();

    // Loads the checkboxes values in an array
      for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
        var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
        if (itemResponse.getItem().getType() == FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX) {
       var  multiple = itemResponse.getResponse();
          Logger.log(multiple[i]);
        }
      }
      var righe = multiple.length - 1;
      for (i = 0; i <= righe; i++) {
        var x = multiple[i];
        movetofolders2(x);
         }
                
    }
    
    
function movetofolders2(folderName) // foldername is where I want to move the files
{ 

    var Files = DriveApp.getFolderById(FoldeRespnseID).getFiles();
      var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(MainFolder).getFolders();
     while (Files.hasNext()) {
        var file = Files.next();
      while(Folder.hasNext()) {
        var child = Folder.next();
        var FName=child.getName();
        if (folderName===FName)
        {
        var sId =child.getId()
        var sdestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sId);
        // Move files to the folder.
        var UfileName = file.getName().toString();
        var driveFile =   DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
        driveFile.makeCopy(UfileName,sdestFolder);
    }
   }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand much of your code, but one way to do this is to create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that executes a function when the form is submitted.
This function would then receive an [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) with the submitted answers and, from that, you can [get](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#getresponse) the folders selected by the user as well as the IDs of the uploaded files.

Once you have the uploaded file and the destination folders, you can copy it using [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopydestination).

Based on the above, one way to implement it would be:

```
function onSubmit(event) {
  const mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ABC123');
  const folderChoiceQuestionIndex = 0;
  const fileUploadQuestionIndex = 1;

  // Get submitted responses
  const responses = event.response.getItemResponses();

  // Get uploaded file based on its ID
  const uploadedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(responses[fileUploadQuestionIndex].getResponse());

  // Copy the uploaded file to the destination folders 
  const destinationFoldersNames = responses[folderChoiceQuestionIndex].getResponse();
  for (const destinationFolderName of destinationFoldersNames) {
    const destinationFolder = mainFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
    uploadedFile.makeCopy(destinationFolder);
  }
}
```

If you want to move more than one file, you'd probably need to include a loop to go through all the questions that correspond to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support:
My intent was to upload 1 to 5 files thru a GOOGLE FORM and then move the files in subfolders (1 to 47) chosen by the users (checkboxes) and then delete the uploaded files from the main folder and upload folder.
Solved:

```
const FFolderUploadsID='Put the ID of the upload file folder';
const MainFolder='Put the ID of the main folder' //where i have the 47 subfolders;

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1].getItemResponses();
  rename();// rename the files uploaded with the '- Username'
// Loads the checkboxes values 
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    if (itemResponse.getItem().getType() == FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX) {
   var  multiple = itemResponse.getResponse();
    }
  }
  var righe = multiple.length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i <= righe; i++) {
    var x = multiple[i];
    movetofolders2(x);
     }
     
     emptyFolder();
}

function emptyFolder()
{ var Ffiles = DriveApp.getFolderById(FFolderUploadsID).getFiles();
  while (Ffiles.hasNext()) {
  var files = Ffiles.next();
  files.setTrashed(true);
  }
}


function rename() {
  var Ffiles = DriveApp.getFolderById(FFolderUploadsID).getFiles();
  while (Ffiles.hasNext()) {
  var files = Ffiles.next();
  oldfilename=files.getName();
  var indexOldFileName = oldfilename.indexOf("-")-1;
  var newFileName = oldfilename.slice(0, indexOldFileName);
  var indexOldFileExt = oldfilename.lastIndexOf(".");
  var newFileExt = oldfilename.slice(indexOldFileExt);
  var modName = newFileName + newFileExt.split(" ").join("");
  //modName = modName.split(" ").join("");
  files.setName(modName);
  TrashFiles(modName);
   }
  
}



function TrashFiles(modName) {
  var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    if (fileName.includes(modName)) {
      file.setTrashed(true)
    }
  }
}


function movetofolders2(folderName) // foldername is where i want to move the files
{ var Files = DriveApp.getFolderById(FFolderUploadsID).getFiles();
  var Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(MainFolder).getFolders();
 var fatto=false;
  while(Folder.hasNext() && fatto===false) {
    var child = Folder.next();
    var FName=child.getName();
    if (folderName===FName)
    {
      var sId =child.getId()
      var sdestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sId);
      // Move files to the folder.
      while (Files.hasNext()) {
      var file = Files.next();

     var UfileName = file.getName().toString();
     var driveFile =   DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
     driveFile.makeCopy(UfileName,sdestFolder);
     fatto=true;
    }
   }
  }
}
```